# Get the first space on the left of varchar SQL

Tags: sql, varchar

I have an Nvarchar column which contains 'John Smith    '

I want to divide it to 'John Smith' and '    '

Any idea how to do that? I tried the length but it don't take in consideration the left spaces

Comment: SQL Server has function LTRIM(String), RTRIM() and SPLIT() functions.It may vary on other SQL Implementation like MySQL or Oracle, but they are likely to have similar function.

Comment: Which RDBMS? MS SQL Server, or something else? Many string functions are platform-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function returns 2 times the string length, including the space, for an nvarchar:

```
DATALENGTH(@variable)
```

So `LEFT(@variable, LEN(@variable))` and `RIGHT(@variable, DATALENGTH(@variable) / 2 - LEN(@variable))` should work.

I'm assuming from your use of `nvarchar` that this is SQL Server...

Comment: the LEN return the value,without put in concideration the left space

Comment: Yes. So DATALENGTH does take it into account, LEN doesn't, the difference allows you to split off that space or spaces. Try the code I posted.

Comment: DECLARE @a VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @b varchar(10)

SET @a = '1'
SET @b = '1 ' --with trailing blank


SET @b = LEFT(@b, LEN(@b))
 SET @b = RIGHT(@b, DATALENGTH(@b) / 2 )

 print @b

SELECT 1
WHERE 
    @a = @b 
AND @a NOT LIKE @b
AND @b LIKE @a  print @b return nothing could you correct for me

Comment: But you've already lost the original definition of `@b` when you `SET @b = LEFT(@b, LEN(@b))`. So you have removed the trailing space. Set it to a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a query, try:

```
...
rtrim(MyColumn) NoTrailingSpaces,
right(MyColumn, len(MyColumn) - len(rtrim(MyColumn)) ) TrailingSpacesOnly,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

-- PARSE OUT THE PADDING FROM THE DATA. REPLACE THE PADDING CHARACTER IF YOU LIKE

```
DECLARE @js varchar(50)
DECLARE @M INT
DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @C CHAR
DECLARE @WORD VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @LPAD VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @RPAD VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @LEFT_PADDING_CHARACTER CHAR
DECLARE @RIGHT_PADDING_CHARACTER CHAR
DECLARE @TERMINATOR_CHARACTER CHAR

-- INIT THE STRINGS
SELECT @LPAD = ''
SELECT @RPAD = ''
SELECT @WORD = ''
SELECT @LEFT_PADDING_CHARACTER = ' '
SELECT @RIGHT_PADDING_CHARACTER = ' '
SELECT @TERMINATOR_CHARACTER = '~'  
SELECT @js = '    John Smith '
SELECT @js = @js + @TERMINATOR_CHARACTER    -- ADD TO CALC THE LENGTH
SELECT @I = 1                               -- FIRST CHARACTER
SELECT @M = LEN(@JS)                        -- LAST CHARACTER

WHILE @I < @M               -- PARSE OUT THE LEFT PADDING
BEGIN
    SELECT @C = SUBSTRING(@js, @I, 1)   
    IF @C = @LEFT_PADDING_CHARACTER SELECT  @LPAD = @LPAD + @C
    ELSE GOTO PARSERIGHTPADDING
    SELECT @I = @I + 1
END

PARSERIGHTPADDING:
SELECT @I = LEN(@JS) -1     -- POINT TO THE LAST CHAR
SELECT @M = 1           -- POINT TO THE FIRST CHAR
SELECT @js = LTRIM(@JS)     -- TRIM OFF THE LEFT PADDING
SELECT @js = REPLACE(@js, @TERMINATOR_CHARACTER, '' -- TRIM OFF THE TERMINATOR

WHILE @M < @I               -- PARSE OUT THE RIGHT PADDING
BEGIN       
    SELECT @C = SUBSTRING(@js, @I, 1)
    IF @C = @RIGHT_PADDING_CHARACTER SELECT  @RPAD = @RPAD + @C
    ELSE GOTO REMOVEPADDINGS
    SELECT @I = @I - 1
END

REMOVEPADDINGS:
SELECT  @WORD = LTRIM(RTRIM(@js))

-- SELECT THE RESULTS TO VIEW THEM @LPAD AND @RPAD SHOULD BE BLANK
SELECT @LPAD [LPAD], @WORD [WORD], @RPAD [RPAD]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loot at the example:

```
DECLARE @js NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'John Smith '
SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(@js, 1) = NCHAR(32) THEN SUBSTRING(@js, 1, DATALENGTH(@js)/2-1) ELSE @js END JohnSmith,
 CASE WHEN RIGHT(@js, 1) = NCHAR(32) THEN NCHAR(32) ELSE N'' END Space
```

Comment: why NCHAR(32) , I don't know the LENGTH of either the padding and the word length

Comment: NCHAR(32) is the space character. But you're right, this doesn't deal with padding of any length other than 1.

Comment: You asket to split last space from the others - i did it, if you want to split to string and its trailing spaceS - then I'll write smth. else. Be specific and exact in your questions